# What's the atmospheric drag coefficient of a Falcon 9 at launch (sub-sonic, large fairing)

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, aerodynamics, atmospheric-drag, simulation

While I said just a few hours ago that ["There's *almost* no such thing as a dumb question!](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16880/#comment43047_16880) this one just might sound like one.

I'm making some slides about first principles thinking applied to engineering problems, and Elon Musk has several good quotes, one for example at a [TED talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/elon_musk_the_mind_behind_tesla_spacex_solarcity) where near the end he says something like “...boil things down to their fundamental truths and reason up from there.” I'm using both Tesla model S and Falcon 9/Falcon Heavy as examples.

For the Tesla Model S, you can get the approximate required battery size easily from a range and speed (400km, 110kph), cross-sectional area (25 square feet), and drag coefficient of 0.24, plus the [rolling resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance) of good tires, 90% overall efficiency and another kilowatt or two for air conditioning, computer&display, and maybe some music.

I wanted to add the [drag coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient) of a Falcon 9 rocket as a tangential comment only. I don't need an exact number, but something in the ballpark, and I have no idea where to begin.

Assume sub-sonic, flying straight, with a reasonably large payload fairing. It doesn't have to be a Falcon 9 - any rocket somewhat representative is fine.

If there is a plot of drag coeficient vs speed that extends to supersonic, that would be really very helpful also. This is back-of-the-envelope I'm doing here.

Is it better or worse than the "Long Cylinder" below?

[image: Measured Drag Coefficients]

Image from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:14ilf1l.svg

Comment: Braeunig's Saturn V simulation page has a graph of Cd versus Mach number; it's a rough approximation based on the figures for the Atlas rocket, but better than nothing.

Comment: Indeed, there is useful discussion and plots at [http://www.braeunig.us/apollo/saturnV.htm](http://www.braeunig.us/apollo/saturnV.htm).

Comment: That page is, like, the source of 1/3 of my points on here.

Comment: Oops! Didn't mean to reveal trade secrets.

Comment: Haha, not at all -- I normally link it, but I was on my phone when I made my first comment.

Comment: link barroque, new one and plots [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW99J.gif), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXnqu.gif) and http://www.braeunig.us/space/index_top.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much better than the long cylinder from your example, because its drag is dominated by the flat face on the front. Count on 0.25 for a [long cylinder terminated by a nose cone](http://www.aerospaceweb.org/question/aerodynamics/q0231.shtml) (maybe a bit more due to the reduction in diameter below the fairing).

Comment: I see. The same way the long cylinder is lower than the short cylinder, the nose-coned long cylinder is better than the cone alone. Thanks for being clear and quick!

Comment: Actually, looking at the second plot with the subtitle "Drag coefficient of blunt nose and rounded nose cylinders versus fineness ratio l/d", would an F9 with a big fairing be around l/d of about 8 to 10, with a drag coefficient of about 0.2 to 0.25 or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: You're right, 0.4 is too high. IDK how the step in diameter from the fairing to the stages affects this though.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean.